# Probability that one random variable is between two others

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Suppose there are 3 random variables, $X, Y$ and $Z$. They are all independently and uniformly distributed $[0,1]$. How do you calculate the probability, conditional on $X$, that $X$ is between $Y$ and $Z$?

The solution says that the answer is $2(1-X)X$, but it doesn't really explain it too much. I only understand that it's multiplied by 2 because you consider the probability $Z<X<Y$ and $Y<X<Z$, but I don't understand how to get $(1-X)X$ for each.

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: The answer--a probability--must therefore be a *number,* but the answer you quote--$2(1-X)X$--is a *random variable.*  That makes no sense.  It would make sense by changing the question: namely, *conditional* on $X,$ what is the chance that $X$ lies between $Y$ and $Z$?  Please check the statement of the question and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Hint: given a value of $X,$ say $X=x,$ what is the chance that $Z\lt x$?  What is the chance that $Y \gt x$?  What does the independence assumption of $(X,Y,Z)$ permit you to do with those chances?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.